# output a stored file from a folder filesystem with java

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, outputstream

I have this problem.
I use spring and I store the attached file (doc,pdf,png...) into the server file system.
Then I save the path and name of the file into my db.
Now how can I read this file as a link into the browser?

I thought to write the file into a web position and give this location to the browser.
is it a good practice?
But how can I delete the file after visualization?

I hope the question is clear.

[image]

to write I use:

```
 /** what write for reach temp-file folder (my project name is intranet)
   I thougth TEMP_FOLDER=""/intranet/resources/temp-files/";
   but It doesnt work. ioexception (The system cannot find the path specified)
 */
 final static String TEMP_FOLDER=?????

public static String createTempFile(String originalPathFile,String fileName){
String tempPathFile="";
try {
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(originalPathFile);
    tempPathFile=TEMP_FOLDER+fileName;
    File tempFile = new File(tempPathFile);

    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
    int read = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        out.write(bytes, 0, read);
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
     System.out.println("Error while Creating File in Java" + ioe);
}

return tempPathFile;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now how can I read this file as a link into the browser?

Place the following link in your JSP

```
<a href="<c:url value="/fileDownloadController/downloadFile?filename=xyz.txt"/>" title="Download xyz.txt"></a>
```

In your controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/fileDownloadController")
public class FileDownloadController
{
    @RequestMapping("/downloadFile")
    public void downloadFile( 
        @RequestParam String filename,
        HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = new FileInputStream("/tmp/" + filename); // I assume files are at /tmp
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            response.setHeader(
                "Content-Disposition",
                "attachment;filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
            outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            while( 0 < ( bytesRead = in.read( buffer ) ) )
            {
                outputStream.write( buffer, 0, bytesRead );
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if ( null != in )
            {
                in.close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another answer that can be useful for people entering in this question using IOUtils:

```
IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream("filename"), outputStream);
```